# python: entropy conditions for characters

Tags: python, entropy

I would like it to calculate entropies based on the Polish alphabet and the signs used:

- if only uppercase or lowercase letters for 32
- if they are both small and large for 64
- if there are numbers +10
- if there are special characters +33

Unfortunately, the second formula for these conditions does not work for me. When I type "Apple" it pops up
NameError: name 'entropia2' is not defined

`````
import math

def entropy_poland(n):
    print("Znaki nie powtarzają się, więc liczymy ze wzoru Hartleya: ")
    if count_upper == True and count_lower == False and count_other == False and count_number == False:
        entropy2 = math.log2(32)
    elif count_upper == False and count_lower == True and count_other == False and count_number == False:
        entropy2 = math.log2(32)
    elif count_upper == False and count_lower == False and count_other == False and count_number == False:
        entropy2 = math.log2(64)
    elif count_upper == True and count_lower == False and count_other == False and count_number == True:
        entropy2 = math.log2(42)
    elif count_upper == False and count_lower == True and count_other == False and count_number == True:
        entropy2 = math.log2(42)
    elif count_upper == False and count_lower == False and count_other == False and count_number == True:
        entropy2 = math.log2(74)
    elif count_upper == False and count_lower == True and count_other == True and count_number == False:
        entropy2 = math.log2(65)
    elif count_upper == True and count_lower == False and count_other == True and count_number == False:
        entropy2 = math.log2(65)
    elif count_upper == False and count_lower == False and count_other == True and count_number == False:
        entropy2 = math.log2(97)
    elif count_upper == True and count_lower == False and count_other == True and count_number == True:
        entropy2 = math.log2(75)
    elif count_upper == False and count_lower == True and count_other == True and count_number == True:
        entropy2 = math.log2(75)
    elif count_upper == False and count_lower == False and count_other == True and count_number == True:
        entropy2 = math.log2(107)
    return entropy2


count_number = False
count_upper = False
count_lower = False
count_other = False

odp = "Reks"

for ascii in odp:
    if chr(32) <= ascii <= chr(47) or chr(58) <= ascii <= chr(64) or chr(91) <= ascii <= chr(96) or chr(
            123) <= ascii <= chr(126):
        count_other = True
    if chr(48) <= ascii <= chr(57):
        count_number = True
    if chr(65) <= ascii <= chr(90):
        count_upper = True
    if chr(97) <= ascii <= chr(122):
        count_lower = True


print(entropy_poland(odp))
````
`````

Comment: I can't replicate the error. Please post a [mcve]. Since the code you posted never tries to *use* the variable `entropia2`, it isn't capable of throwing that error. It does seem odd that in most places in the `else` clause you are using `entropy2` but that in one place you are using `entropia2`.

Comment: I tried to minimize the code and I forgot to change the entropy2

Answer (score 1):

If you insert the line

```
print(count_upper,count_lower,count_other,count_number)
```

at the beginning of the definition of `entropy_poland` you will see that it prints

```
True True False False
```

before throwing the error. That Boolean combination is *not* one of the combinations covered by your clauses. There are 16 Boolean combinations of 4 variables, but you have only defined `entropy2` for 12 of them. You need to rethink your logic, either adding an `else` clause or perhaps raising (then handling) an error if this Boolean combination is in fact an error.